# Need seismic data and digital well log data from the same area?

Tags: geology, geophysics, seismology

I am currently working on a project that involves the input of **seismic attributes (instantaneous amplitude, instantaneous frequency etc.)** to a machine learning/deep learning model (eg. A Neural Network) . The output given by the model are **petrophysical** properties such as **Porosity,Permeability** etc.

To create this model, I need **seismic** as well as **digital well log data** from the same area which I have not been able to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conoco Philips made the Poseidon data available including 3D seismic data and well logs.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7brcf-eGK8CRUhfRW9rSG91bW8

All data is made available under the terms of the Creative Commons “Attribution 3.0 Australia” licence, be sure to treat it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The SEG has a list of open file seismic data sets here: https://wiki.seg.org/wiki/Open_data

For a number of these surveys well logs are also given.

Comment: I need ,both the well log and seismic data to be from the same area. SEG's data does not fulfil that requirement.

Comment: A number of the links on that page have well logs as well as seismic.  For example the Poseidon survey in Australia: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7brcf-eGK8Cbk9ueHA0QUU4Zjg

Answer (score 2):

There is a data repository https://opendtect.org/osr/ . from what I understand, it is a repository made for OpendTect and maintain by dGB Earth Sciences. There you can find seismic and well data.
Also New Zeland gov has published this https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6384901298944380928. That one, I didn't have the chance to work with, but should work fine for seens you need. Austarlia has a similar open data base but can't find the link now.